# Discord.py How to get message of mentioned user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm updating an older Bot that worked fine before the last updates. And most commands were kinda easy to get to work.
In a command, user A should specify another user B and a number. User B is mentioned and the number goes through a class that rolls the number of dice for him/her. After that has happened and a number has been generated, user B should now name a number that also goes through this class and forms a counter value.
This works up to the point where feedback from user B is expected. After that I get the error "Client.wait_for() got an unexpected keyword argument 'author'".

```
@bot.command()
async def bam(ctx, op: discord.Member, a: int):
    __wuerfe , __erfolg , __sechs = wurf(a)
    __wuerfe.clear()
    while __sechs > 0:
        ___wuerfe , ___erfolg , ___sechs = wurf(__sechs)
        ___wuerfe.clear()
        __sechs = ___sechs
        ___sechs = 0
        __erfolg += ___erfolg
    if __erfolg == 0:
        await ctx.send("{} schlug voll daneben!".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
    else:
        await ctx.send("{} griff ".format(ctx.message.author.mention) + str(op.mention) + " mit **" + str(__erfolg) + "** Erfolgen an! " + str(op.nick) + " gib bitte deinen Wert für physische Verteidigung ein.")
        antwort = await bot.wait_for(author = op, timeout=90)
        antwortVer = antwort.content
        verteidigung = int(antwortVer)

        wuerfeVer , erfolgVer , sechsVer = wurf(verteidigung)
        wuerfeVer.clear()
        while sechsVer > 0:
            wuerfeVer2 , erfolgVer2 , sechsVer2 = wurf(sechsVer)
            wuerfeVer2.clear()
            sechsVer = sechsVer2
            sechsVer2 = 0
            erfolgVer += erfolgVer2
```

I understand that the strucutres I'm using are outdated, but I can't find a working way to get the mentioned user B and await his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code i use for this, you can add a timeout still but this can be edited to be whatever member and channel you want(or removed)

```
def check(message):
      return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot to understand the new structure. Could figure out how to update the rest of my code!